# Populating a VueJS data property through a strongly bound List<T> DOM in a razor view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vuejs2, asp.net-core-mvc

I am working on Asp.Net Core MVC Web application and using VueJs for front-end rendering/manipulation. Ultimately, I want to implement a Master-Detail in Razor View using VueJS where Detail Rows (Line Items) could be added/removed dynamically but for now, I am just trying to access a `List<T>` type Domain Object Model in VueJS Data and trying to add/remove rows of data dynamically.

Here is my code:

#### ViewModel

```
public class VueJsTestModelDetail
{
    public int DetailId { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [EmailAddress]
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

#### Controller

```
public IActionResult Vue()
{
    VueJsTestModel viewModel = new VueJsTestModel();
    viewModel.Id = 1;
    viewModel.Name = "Saud Nasir";
    viewModel.Designation = "Software Engineer";

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        viewModel.VueJsTestModelDetails.Add(new VueJsTestModelDetail { Id = 1, DetailId = i + 1, Email = "xyz_" + (i + 1).ToString() + "@abc.com" });
    }
    return View(viewModel.VueJsTestModelDetails);
}
```

#### Razor View

```
@model List<Vue.js_Hello_World.Models.VueJsTestModelDetail> 

<div id="app">
    <div class="container border" style="border: thin;">
        <div class="mt-2">
            <form asp-action="Vue">
                <div class="form-group" style="text-align:right; width:100%">
                    <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" />
                    <input v-on:click="View" type="button" value="View" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" />
                </div>
                <ul>
                    <li v-for="(detail, index) in DetailData">
                        <h4>{{detail.DetailID}}</h4>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### VueJS Script

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>

<script>
var vm = new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data: {
        DetailData: '@Model',
     },
    methods: {
        View: function () {
            alert(this.DetailData);
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

I want to populate `DetailData` with the values that I send from controller but through this code, `DetailData` is populated with strings that contains the name of the data type. (e.g. "`List<Vue.js_Hello_World.Models.VueJSTestModelDetails>`"). I want to store actual values in `DetailData` on page load, for example:

```
DetailData[0].DetailID = 1, 
DetailData[0].Id = 0, 
DetailData[0].Email = "xyz_1@abc.com"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is happening is that outputting @Model is the equivalent of calling ToString() on the Model. Instead what you want to do is output the json serialised version of the object.

Replace the line

```
DetailData: '@Model',
```

with the line

```
DetailData: @Json.Serialize(Model),
```

Comment: I cant thank you enough!! made my current task soo much easier.